# Simulating Mixed Nash Equilibria

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I have a $N$ person game where each person has a set of $M$ discrete strategies. I know from the theory that at least one mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium exists.

Can someone please tell me how do I find one of those equilibrium points by numerical simulation?

I can not find in the book any explanation of how to simulate. I just need the basic direction.

I have asked this question in math.stackexchange as well. But I posted here too as I noticed users here are not noticed of questions there. Pardon me if this is wrong practice.

Thank you.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Thank you. but I think it is not a linear system. It is linear only for two player games. From three player up it is non-linear for the best of my knowledge. Correlated equilibria will be a linear system for any number of players but not NE. (See slide 17 of http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~kevinlb/teaching/cs532a%20-%202006-7/lectures/lect8.pdf )

Comment: MLT:  Apologies.  I misread your post as saying there were two players.  I'll leave this up long enough to make sure you see it, then delete the comment.

Comment: What does "numerical simulation" mean?

Comment: @usul It means to find numerically, not analytically. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, an exact equilibrium may not be computable in general, so usually the idea is to specify an error parameter $\epsilon$ and look for an $\epsilon$-equilibrium.

Finding an $\epsilon$-Nash equilibrium is considered a hard problem (it is complete for the complexity class $\mathsf{PPAD}$). So there are no known "fast" algorithms.

One algorithm is called *support enumeration* and covered in [this math.se post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97858/finding-nash-equilibria-using-support-enumeration). You list all possible supports for the players' mixed strategies. Given a set of supports, one can use linear programming to check whether there is a mixed NE with these supports.

Another method (that I believe is still relatively state of the art (?)) is given by Lipton, Markakis, and Mehta (2003) in *Playing Large Games Using Simple Strategies* ([pdf link](https://mpi-sb.mpg.de/departments/d1/teaching/ws11/AGT/NE-LiMaMe03.pdf)). The idea is, given $\epsilon$ and the number of strategies $n$, let $k = 12 \ln n / \epsilon^2$. Enumerate all mixed strategies with probabilities that are a multiple of $1/k$ for each player (there are ${n + k -1 \choose k}^2$ pairs of strategies to look at) and check each pair to see if it is an $\epsilon$-equilibrium; the authors prove that at least one such pair must be.

Both of these are covered in [this 2004 article](http://web.mit.edu/tabbott/Public/final.pdf) "On Algorithms for Nash Equilibria." I am not sure if there is anything faster that has since been discovered; I guess not for the general case, but there are definitely faster algorithms for certain classes of games. One reference would be *On Oblivious PTAS's for Nash Equilibrium* by Daskalakis and Papadimitriou ([arxiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2280)), also *The Approximate Rank of a Matrix and its Algorithmic Applications* by Alon et al from this year's STOC ([pdf link](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/epsrankstoc3.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by "numerical simulation" you mean something in the spirit of an "adaptive dynamics". If I'm right, I could recommend the paper: 
Germano, Fabrizio, and Gabor Lugosi. "Global Nash convergence of Foster and Young's regret testing." Games and Economic Behavior 60.1 (2007): 135-154.
to be found online e.g. [here](http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00000342/01/nash.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If by „Simulating Mixed Nash Equilibria” you simply mean algorithmically finding Nash equilibria, you can find interesting information in the section “3.2 General-player games” available [here](http://www.gambit-project.org/turocy/papers/solving-ncsf.pdf).